# Group array of objects nesting a key in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have an array of objects where these objects can have the same name, and each object has a error key that is an array.

```
const array = [
  {
    name: 'Rafael',
    errors: [ 1, 2 ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Rafael',
    errors: [7]
  },
  {
    name: 'Joao',
    errors: [ 8 ]
  }
]
```

I trying to have the response like this:

```
const response = [
  {
    name: 'Rafael',
    errors: [ 1, 2, 7]
  }, {
    name: 'Joao',
    errors: [8]
  }
]
```

Does anyone have idea to how to do this? I tried to use groupBy of lodash, but I couldnt obtain the response I what

Answer (score 0):

you could use a simple [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of `lodash`, something as following:

```
const array = [
  {
    name: 'Rafael',
    errors: [ 1, 2 ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Rafael',
    errors: [7]
  },
  {
    name: 'Joao',
    errors: [ 8 ]
  }
]

const newArray = array.reduce((list, item) => {
    const {name, errors} = item;
  const nameIndex = list.findIndex(item => item.name === name);
  if(nameIndex === -1){
    list.push(item);
  } else {
    list[nameIndex].errors.push(errors)
  }
  return list
}, []);
```

You can also try it in [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjt39ynx/)